# Create win task to run once and delete immediately using C#

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks

Here is the use case:
- Create a new win task, run immediately and once complete, delete the task.

Here is basic code to create a task using C#.

```
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService(null))
    {
        string projectName = "runnowtest" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        //create new task
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        Trigger mt = null;

        //setup task as Registration trigger
        mt = td.Triggers.AddNew(TaskTriggerType.Registration);
        mt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;

        //delete the task 1 minute after the program ends
        td.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); 

        //run the notepad++ in the task
        td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe"));

        //register task
        Task output = ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(projectName, td);

        //check output
        Console.WriteLine(output != null ? "Task created" : "Task not created");
    }
```

The API doesn't seem to have a property/flag to mark task as run once. I am trying to ensure the above task runs only once and deletes immediately after that. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Why run it via scheduler, when you could just spawn the process directly?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I understand i can run any process directly without scheduler. But, my question is about "usage of Task Scheduler API" to accomplish this.

Comment: This solution does not work for Task Scheduler V1.3. The "Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.NotV1SupportedException" exception is thrown when Version ver = ts.HighestSupportedVersion and Version.major = 1 and Version.Minor = 3.

Answer (score 3):

I know its old but for reference...
To use DeleteExpiredTaskAfter you need to give trigger EndBoundary:

```
var trigger = new RegistrationTrigger{Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), EndBoundary = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50))};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the task XML definition to set all the things not exposed directly by the API.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382559(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection running tasks and you can end them using the Stop() method.

I did in the OnStop method to clean up created tasks, just take the same logic and include it where needed.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    TaskService ts = new TaskService();
    var tasks = ts.GetRunningTasks();
    foreach(var t in tasks)
    {
        t.Stop();
    }
}
```